# Customize the SOLR Default response to custom Search response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

I was working on the POC of accessing the solr via the microservices using spring boot. I am using the Rest template to connect the solr . My query is can we customize the response that solr returns ?.

### For Example:

> solrUri="http://localhost:8983/solr/microServicesPOC/select?q=*:*&wt=json"

When we access the above url, the response solr returns has the docuemnts of fields.  I need to get the results in the format of my Product pojo.

### Snippet:

> resEntity =  solrConfig.getRestTemplate().exchange(solrUri,HttpMethod.POST,entity , Product.class);

To achieve from the above way of rest template, I need the solr to return response in  Product format. Is it possible from SOlr?

> I am not using the solrTemplate or the solrJ. I want the customization from the solr side not on the service side .

Tried customizing the searchHandler ,Writing DocTransformer but none of the methods worked .

Comment: How does Solr know what your Product type looks like?

Comment: I want to customize the search response the solr returns.

Comment: Why do you use rest directly. Have you ever had a look at the spring data solr documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: Yes I had tried that, but our current inplementation has the approach of above way.

Comment: You could do that if you could write your own custom ResponseWriter but I would insist that it's a bad choice for several reasons - supportability, complicated deployment to name a few. Prefer to go for custom layer between that will do a transformation